# Using refresh token fails; was working before

Tags: oauth, box-api

My Box app (using v2 API) keeps track of when an access token expires, and when the app realizes the access token is about to expire, it request a new access token using the refresh token (the reason is that it simpler to avoid errors than to handle them).

I noticed that lately (this definitely was working properly a few months ago), when my app starts up (after more than 1 hour of non-use), the request for a new access token fails! The interesting thing is that at this time, my app has not attempted to use the now expired access token.

Should my app first do a dummy action with the expired access token maybe as a workaround? Again, all this was working as expected when I converted the app over to V2 API. At that time, the refresh token was valid for 14 days.

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Sounds odd. I'll try to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce it, and I'm not able to.  My refresh tokens are all working.  It could be that you are getting an error condition on your refresh that you are not catching.  There are some cases where your admin can decide that the app you are using is no longer approved for your enterprise, and on refresh, you'll be booted out.  Or you may have mis-typed your password enough times that your password is going into "captcha" mode, looking to verify that there's a human, and not a machine on the other end of the wire.

Let me suggest that you log out of the app, and log back in.  You're more likely to get presented with the error, since Box will be giving you the auth screen, and Box handles all the weird cases in their OAuth2 screens.

Yet another reason, that for all the pain of implementing Oauth2, it's worth it to get a better experience for your users.

Comment: Thanks for trying to reproduce. However, the problem remains, a refresh request fails when you log into the app the next day as the first interaction with Box. Again, the same code was working fine before the refresh token was extended from 14 to 60 days. See Fiddler trace at: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40554620/Logs/Box%20Refresh%20Fiddler%20Trace.txt

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40554620/Logs/Box%20Refresh%20Fiddler%20Trace.txt

Comment: I updated the above Fiddler trace in Dropbox with a new trace that clearly showed the problem. Could you please take a look and tell me whether I am issuing an invalid request maybe? Thanks, Peter